# How much is expected loss in training using SSD?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, caffe

Is there any expected loss in training using [SSD](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd)? Say I train one class detection and use 1200 images in training. What would be my expected loss when training is optimum?
We normally stop training when loss doesn't change much? How can I verify that loss is optimum for my training?

Comment: Optimum loss is 0. Whether your net can theoretically reach this optimum one cannot say. Whether it is a good thing to reach optimum = 0 error on the training set is a wholly different question.

Comment: @JanKukacka hi thanks. Say my training achieved minimum loss 5. What are the things I need to look at in training.

Comment: @JanKukacka, I need to come back with some plots for my training so that you have some ideas. I'll come back with plots for loss and learning rate.